# How to fit image in a css grid row without it expanding

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to add an img inside the `.grid-banner` div so that the full img fits inside the div without expanding it.

I have a mosaic style Css grid layout  like so:

[image]

Css

```
.gridContainer {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
  grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
  grid-gap: 2px;
}

.grid-header {
  background-color: red;
  grid-column: 1/13;
  display: flex;
}

.grid-banner {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 1/13;
  grid-row: 2/4;
}

.grid-content {
  background-color: orange;
  grid-column: 1/10;
  grid-row: 4/11;
}

.grid-menu {
  background-color: blue;
  grid-column: 10/12;
  grid-row: 3/11;
}

.grid-footer {
  background-color: purple;
  grid-column: 1/13;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two options, either use a background image and place an 'img' tag inside the grid-banner div.

First Way: Place image inside the grid-banner

```
.grid-banner {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 1/13;
  grid-row: 2/4;
}
.grid-banner img{
width:auto;
max-width:100%;
object-fit:cover;
}
```

Second option: background-image

In this approach you have to add some height to your container, only then background-image can appear.

```
.grid-banner {
  background-color: green;
  grid-column: 1/13;
  grid-row: 2/4;
  min-height:300px;
background-image:url(demo.jpg);
background-attachement:scroll;
background-position:center;
background-size:cover;
background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: I used the second option as it seems to keep the height of my row.  However it does not show the full image.  It seems to cropped

Comment: You probably need to resize your image if you want to fit it properly inside the container. What background-size cover does is scale your image to a larger extent so that it can fill the entire container and everything of image which comes outside of the container is simply get cropped to maintain the aspect ratio of the image.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just fix the height of the grid container:

```
.gridContainer {
   height: 50vh;
   display: grid;
   grid-template-columns: repeat(12, 1fr);
   grid-auto-rows: minmax(50px, auto);
   grid-gap: 2px;
}

.grid-banner img{
   height:100%;
   width:100%;
   object-fit:cover;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't that just cut the mosaic layout to half the size of the screen

Comment: You can try other values. It doesn't matter.